# ^A/m in regex is not working as mdn suggests

Tags: javascript, regex

> ^   ----> 
>       Matches beginning of input. If the multiline flag is set to true, also matches immediately after a line break character.
>
> For example, /^A/ does not match the "A" in "an A", but does match the first "A" in "An A".

Above is documented in mdn  - [under this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes)

Adding /m flag at the end of the regex doesn't work, as it should for all the multiline beginning.
[image: Here's a picture for the same]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the JS code you're using. You didn't say if you were using the multiline flag or which regex and/or string method(s) you're trying.

Comment: Not using any js code. Just running the example in the site I mentioned.

Comment: When I try `^A` at that site it works as expected for me: http://regexr.com/3gr8f

Comment: works [fine](https://regexr.com/3gr8c)

Comment: You are right my bad I was trying it with multiline. Can you check it with multiline by adding /m at the end.

Comment: Jaromanda and I both tested with the multiline flag - **note that at that site you add flags by clicking the flags link, you don't manually type them in the expression.** If you have an example where it doesn't work, please save it and share the link here.

Comment: Got It, Thanks (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `regexr.com`, choosing a flag is not just typing it directly with a slash. You should choose your flag here:

[image: Here]

**P/s:**

> should for all the multiline beginning

So you need global and multiline flags.